# How can i run a specific codeblock in PowerShell as an administrator

Tags: powershell

I want to set registry keys in a PowerShell script but the script has to be executed as the logged in User and only the part where registry keys are set need to run with administrator privileges.

This is what i got yet, unfortunately it is not working:

```
#Run ScriptBlock as admin
$username = ".\admin"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "adminpassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = [pscredential]::new($username,$password)
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden -FilePath "powershell" -Credential $credential - ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{$ScriptBlock -verb runas}'
```

Is there a better way to do it? I'm really new into scripting.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is pointless, you might as well give the user the same (or a limited subset) rights as `.\admin` as he will simply be able to retrieve the credentials from the script... meaning, if the `.\admin` is the only person with write access to the registry key, *he* should be the only one able to (remotely with a script?) change the registry keys.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? (Specifically, _why_ does a logged on user that's not an administrator need to update registry values where they don't have permission?)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart the script is starting a ExSync.exe for the outlook signatures, the .exe has to bee executed by the logged in user otherwise the signatures don‘t work. But when the user starts the program an error message shoes up but it don't affect the system(all user get the error in the event log but only a few gets the error message). With the registry i change the value of DontShowUI to 1 when the program is running and to 0 when the program has stopped running.

Comment: This sounds like a question for whoever wrote your executable: "How do I run your executable without it requiring administrator rights and without a visible GUI?"

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I could solve the problem with giving all the user the specific write permission of the key, that i want to edit in my script.

Comment: Let's get back to my original question: Why do you need for standard users to update that registry value? What problem are you trying to solve that this sounds like the correct solution? (The reason I ask is that this sounds rather like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).)